# Schema validation failed xs:date

Tags: wcf, xsd, schema

I am receiving "Schema validation failed" from the server when calling my WCF service.

The error message returned states that the validation is failing on an element of type "date"

**Response from server**

```
<s:Fault>
  <s:Code>
    <s:Value>s:VCE1001</s:Value>
  </s:Code>
  <s:Reason>
    <s:Text xml:lang="en-GB">Schema validation failed.</s:Text>
  </s:Reason>
  <s:Detail>
    <FaultDetails xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/project.Error_Handler" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Information>Element Name: ExampleDateElement, Line Number: 0, Line Position: 0</Information>
    </FaultDetails>
  </s:Detail>
</s:Fault>
```

**Request to server**

```
          <Message xsi:type="q1:Example_OutboundMessage" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:q1="project_messages">
        <q1:Element1>123456789123</q1:Element1>
        <q1:Element2>
          <Nested1>string123</Nested1>
          <Nested2>string123</Nested2>
        </q1:Element2>
        <q1:Element3>2017-03-28</q1:Element3>
        <q1:ExampleDateElement>2017-03-29</q1:ExampleDateElement>
        <q1:Element4>64bc7ab8-b418-4d23-8d31-47312e838c92</q1:Element4>
      </Message>
```

**Schema**

```
 <xs:complexType name="Example_OutboundMessage">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="vct:OutboundMessage_Type">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Element1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation>
                Info here
              </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:minLength value="12" />
                <xs:maxLength value="13" />
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="Element2" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="vct:Example_Type">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation>
                Info here.
              </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="Element3" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:date">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation>
                Info here.
              </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="ExampleDateElement" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:date">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation>
                Info here.
              </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="Element4" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation>
                Info here.
              </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:minLength value="1" />
                <xs:maxLength value="255" />
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
```

Cannot see anything wrong with the date that is passed in for "ExampleDateElement".
Also the schema seems to pass for the date element above, even though the date formats are the same. It even fails if the dates are exactly the same.

Comment: Element1 would fail the minLength facet, but the 2 dates look ok...

Comment: @Sprotty oh yeah you're right - I omitted the original request data (apart form the date elements) but missed that part. I've updated the question

Comment: Can you post the service code which generates this fault? Also the service code which does the validation? It's possible that the copy of the schema being validated against on the service is not the same as the one you have posted.

Comment: @tomredfern That's the strange thing, the error message states the element that the schema is failing on. I am viewing the server schema and comparing it to the schema in code and they are exactly the same. I am going to re publish everything and see what happens